# Printing two multi-line strings, end='' doesn't put them side by side

Tags: python

I'm trying to display large numbers in the terminal using graphical characters, for example I have:

```
def nos(n):
    if n == 1: return("""
#
#
#
#
#
""")
    if n == 2: return("""
###
  #
###
#
###
""")
```

I try to display these like:

```
for i in [1,2]:
    print(nos(i), end = " ")
```

The desired output is like so:

```
# ###
#   #
# ###
# #
# ###
```

But instead I get

```
#
#
#
#
# ###
  #
###
#
###
```

Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What is the value of `nos(i)`? Does it have a newline in it?

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: (Just because `print()` won't *add* a newline, doesn't mean existing newlines in the value you are printing won't still be output. `print()` won't *remove* newlines).

Comment: I rewrote the question to meet the standards here - showing expected vs actual output, and directly asking the question while cutting out everything irrelevant.

Comment: The `print` is going to print the entirety of `nos(1)`, including all the newlines embedded in it. Then it will print a space followed by the entirety of `nos(2)`. Knowing that you should be able to figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

1. split each *graphical* number string by new line, `\n`
2. join corresponding lines of each number with space, 
   (You might want to pad each line for other numbers than 1)
3. print the resulting string

```py
def nos(n):
    if n == 1:
        return("""
#
#
#
#
#
""")
    if n == 2:
        return("""
###
  #
###
#
###
""")


lst = [1, 2]

def multi_num(lst):
    nums = list(nos(i).split('\n') for i in lst)
    for i in range(1, 6):
        result = ' '.join(num[i] for num in nums)
        print(result)

multi_num(lst)
```

```
# ###
#   #
# ###
# #
# ###
```